# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null; in react using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

Currently using axios to get data from a json placeholder and displaying it through a button 'GET' in react. I get the the common TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null error, which means that ive missplaced the code. However I dont know where to place the code in its order

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


function getTodos() {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
  })
    .then(res => showOutput(res))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}


function showOutput(res) {
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = `
  <div class="card card-body mb-4">
    <h5>Status: ${res.status}</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Headers
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <pre>${JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Data
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <pre>${JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Config
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <pre>${JSON.stringify(res.config, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
`;
}

document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click',getTodos);

function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary my-3" id="get">GET</button>
        <div id="res"></div>
      </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

This is all in the react app in the App.js file. Any help? thanks.

Comment: this looks strange. you say you are using react, but you directly generate and interact with the html dom (setting innerHtml, adding event listeners etc.)

Comment: If I am trying to pick an item from the DOM using the ID attr. I will always make sure that there is an element with that specified ID attr. If not, the value of that item will be null by default, which would not cause any issues as such. But as soon as you start using that element's value. You will get type error because the element where you are trying to do logical operations is set to "null".

Comment: Furthermore, the whole point of using react as a library is to save ourselves from the expensive DOM manipulations. try to use state and props as much as you can and stay away from any sort of code that starts with the keyword "document". :D

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do this:

```
    const [Resp, setResp] = useState({});


    function getTodos() {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
  })
    .then(res => setResp(res))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}


    function App() {
      return (
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-3" id="get">GET</button>
            <div id="res">
              <div class="card card-body mb-4">
    <h5>Status: {{Resp? Resp.status : "Loading..."}}</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Headers
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <pre>{{ Resp? JSON.stringify(resp.headers, null, 2) : "Loading..."}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Data
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <pre>{{Resp? JSON.stringify(Resp.data, null, 2) : "Loading.." }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-header">
      Config
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <pre>{{Resp? JSON.stringify(Resp.config, null, 2) ? "Loading..." }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    }
```

If it's not a must to create the HTML from a function I would go with a state where you save your response `res => setResp(res)`

Then in HTML you first check if response is set
`{{Resp? 'variable to show if true' : 'variable to show if false' }}`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way, in JSX syntax

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const [html, setHTML] = useState('');

  const getTodos = () => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
    })
      .then(res => showOutput(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  const showOutput = res => {
    setHTML(<> 
    <div class="card card-body mb-4">
      <h5>Status: {res.status}</h5>
    </div>
  
    <div class="card mt-3">
      <div class="card-header">
        Headers
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(res.headers, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="card mt-3">
      <div class="card-header">
        Data
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="card mt-3">
      <div class="card-header">
        Config
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(res.config, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>);
  }
  
  return (
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary my-3" onClick={getTodos}>GET</button>
        <div id="res">
          {html}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```